# more FP way instead of if/else

Tags: scala

Want to get more FP way development. In my case DAO can return Object or None.
But I should guarantee if all object exists

implemented like this

```
def get(...): String = {
    val user1 = UserDAO.getUser(...)
    val user1 = UserDAO.getUser(...)
    val userN = UserDAO.getUser(...)

if (user1.isEmpty || ser2.isEmpty || ... ) {
 return "error"
} else {
 ... 
}
```

Can it implement more functional way. without mess if / else  ?

BR!

Comment: An if-else expression isn't "not FP", but do get rid of the unnecessary `return`.

Answer (score 3):

Make a list of the arguments you pass to getUser, and use `map`and `forall`:

```
val userIds = List(...)
val dbUsers = userIds.map(UserDAO.getUser)
```

if you do not want to use if/else you can do this, though it feels somewhat upside down and probably totally obfuscates your intention:

```
dbUsers.collectFirst { case user if user.isEmpty => "error" } getOrElse { "ok" }
```

However, afaik if/else is not really that much frowned upon in fp (or at least among scala developers), so you could as well write it in a more expressive and also concise way:

```
if (dbUsers.forall(_.nonEmpty)) "ok" else "error"
```

or, in inverse logic:

```
if (dbUsers.exists(_.isEmpty)) "error" else "ok"
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider

```
if (Seq(user1,user2,userN).exists(_.isEmpty)) "error"
else ""
```

With `exists` on `isEmpty` we check whether any of the users is not defined. This approach halts the iteration over `Seq` as the first item that holds the predicate is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for-comprehension to flatmap over all 3 `Option[User]` and specify what happens if all 3 users exist.

Then use `getOrElse` to specify what should happen if any of those users is a `None`

```
def get(...): String = {
    val namesOpt = for {
        u1 <- UserDAO.getUser(...)
        u2 <- UserDAO.getUser(...)
        u3 <- UserDAO.getUser(...)
    } yield u1.name + u2.name + u3.name

    namesOpt getOrElse "error"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val users = /* collection of Option[User] types */
users.find(!_.isDefined).fold("ok") { _ => "error" }
```

Or..

```
users.find(_.isEmpty).fold("ok") { _ => "error" }
```

Comment: `!_.isDefined` could be rewritten as `_.isEmpty`.